# Buying ram to avoid chunking for 30-50Gb plus files

Tags: python, csv, pandas, ram, chunking

I use pandas to read very large csv files, which also are gzipped.
I unzip into csv files which are approx 30-50GB.
I chunk the files and process/manipulate them.
Finally add the relevant data to HDF5 files which I compress

It works fine but is slow since I have to deal with one file per day and have several years worth of data (600TB uncompressed csv)

Could buying more ram be a good way to avoid chunking and speed up the process say 64GB/128GB?
But will this make pandas slow and unwieldy?
Am I right in saying that switching to C++ could speed up the process but I still suffer from the read process and having to deal with the data in chunks.
Finally does anyone have any thoughts on the best way to handle this.

By the way once the job is done i wont have to go back and deal with the data again so want just to get it to work in reasonable time so writing some thing that parallel processes might be nice but with limited experience in that area it would take me a while to build it so prefer not to unless that is the only option.

Update. I think it would be easier to see the code. I don't believe the code is particularly slow in anyway. I think the technology/methodology might be.

```
def txttohdf(path, contract):
    #create dataframes for trade and quote
    dftrade = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["datetime", "Price", "Volume"])
    dfquote = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["datetime", "BidPrice", "BidSize","AskPrice", "AskSize"])
    #create an hdf5 file with high compression and table so we can append
    hdf = pd.HDFStore(path + contract + '.h5', complevel=9, complib='blosc')
    hdf.put('trade', dftrade, format='table', data_columns=True)
    hdf.put('quote', dfquote, format='table', data_columns=True)
    #date1 = date(start).strftime('%Y%m%d')
    #date2 = date(end).strftime('%Y%m%d')
    #dd = [date1 + timedelta(days=x) for x in range((date2-date1).days + 1)]
    #walkthrough directories
    for subdir, dir, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            #check if contract has name
            #print(file)
                #create filename from directory and file 

            filename = os.path.join(subdir, file)
                #read in csv
            if filename.endswith('.gz'):

                df = pd.read_csv(gzip.open(filename),header=0,iterator=True,chunksize = 10000, low_memory =False,  names = ['RIC','Date','Time','GMTOffset','Type','ExCntrbID','LOC','Price','Volume','MarketVWAP','BuyerID','BidPrice','BidSize','NoBuyers','SellerID','AskPrice','AskSize','NoSellers','Qualifiers','SeqNo','ExchTime','BlockTrd','FloorTrd','PERatio','Yield','NewPrice','NewVol','NewSeqNo','BidYld','AskYld','ISMABidYld','ISMAAskYld','Duration','ModDurtn','BPV','AccInt','Convexity','BenchSpd','SwpSpd','AsstSwpSpd','SwapPoint','BasePrice','UpLimPrice','LoLimPrice','TheoPrice','StockPrice','ConvParity','Premium','BidImpVol','AskImpVol','ImpVol','PrimAct','SecAct','GenVal1','GenVal2','GenVal3','GenVal4','GenVal5','Crack','Top','FreightPr','1MnPft','3MnPft','PrYrPft','1YrPft','3YrPft','5YrPft','10YrPft','Repurch','Offer','Kest','CapGain','Actual','Prior','Revised','Forecast','FrcstHigh','FrcstLow','NoFrcts','TrdQteDate','QuoteTime','BidTic','TickDir','DivCode','AdjClose','PrcTTEFlag','IrgTTEFlag','PrcSubMktId','IrgSubMktId','FinStatus','DivExDate','DivPayDate','DivAmt','Open','High','Low','Last','OpenYld','HighYld','LowYld','ShortPrice','ShortVol','ShortTrdVol','ShortTurnnover','ShortWeighting','ShortLimit','AccVolume','Turnover','ImputedCls','ChangeType','OldValue','NewValue','Volatility','Strike','Premium','AucPrice','Auc Vol','MidPrice','FinEvalPrice','ProvEvalPrice','AdvancingIssues','DecliningIssues','UnchangedIssues','TotalIssues','AdvancingVolume','DecliningVolume','UnchangedVolume','TotalVolume','NewHighs','NewLows','TotalMoves','PercentageChange','AdvancingMoves','DecliningMoves','UnchangedMoves','StrongMarket','WeakMarket','ChangedMarket','MarketVolatility','OriginalDate','LoanAskVolume','LoanAskAmountTradingPrice','PercentageShortVolumeTradedVolume','PercentageShortPriceTradedPrice','ForecastNAV','PreviousDaysNAV','FinalNAV','30DayATMIVCall','60DayATMIVCall','90DayATMIVCall','30DayATMIVPut','60DayATMIVPut','90DayATMIVPut','BackgroundReference','DataSource','BidSpread','AskSpread','ContractPhysicalUnits','Miniumumquantity','NumberPhysicals','ClosingReferencePrice','ImbalanceQuantity','FarClearingPrice','NearClearingPrice','OptionAdjustedSpread','ZSpread','ConvexityPremium','ConvexityRatio','PercentageDailyReturn','InterpolatedCDSBasis','InterpolatedCDSSpread','ClosesttoMaturityCDSBasis','SettlementDate','EquityPrice','Parity','CreditSpread','Delta','InputVolatility','ImpliedVolatility','FairPrice','BondFloor','Edge','YTW','YTB','SimpleMargin','DiscountMargin','12MonthsEPS','UpperTradingLimit','LowerTradingLimit','AmountOutstanding','IssuePrice','GSpread','MiscValue','MiscValueDescription'])
                #parse date time this is quicker than doing it while we read it in
                for chunk in df:
                    chunk['datetime'] = chunk.apply(lambda row: datetime.datetime.strptime(row['Date']+ ':' + row['Time'],'%d-%b-%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f'), axis=1)
                    #df = df[~df.comment.str.contains('ALIAS')]
                #drop uneeded columns inc date and time
                    chunk = chunk.drop(['Date','Time','GMTOffset','ExCntrbID','LOC','MarketVWAP','BuyerID','NoBuyers','SellerID','NoSellers','Qualifiers','SeqNo','ExchTime','BlockTrd','FloorTrd','PERatio','Yield','NewPrice','NewVol','NewSeqNo','BidYld','AskYld','ISMABidYld','ISMAAskYld','Duration','ModDurtn','BPV','AccInt','Convexity','BenchSpd','SwpSpd','AsstSwpSpd','SwapPoint','BasePrice','UpLimPrice','LoLimPrice','TheoPrice','StockPrice','ConvParity','Premium','BidImpVol','AskImpVol','ImpVol','PrimAct','SecAct','GenVal1','GenVal2','GenVal3','GenVal4','GenVal5','Crack','Top','FreightPr','1MnPft','3MnPft','PrYrPft','1YrPft','3YrPft','5YrPft','10YrPft','Repurch','Offer','Kest','CapGain','Actual','Prior','Revised','Forecast','FrcstHigh','FrcstLow','NoFrcts','TrdQteDate','QuoteTime','BidTic','TickDir','DivCode','AdjClose','PrcTTEFlag','IrgTTEFlag','PrcSubMktId','IrgSubMktId','FinStatus','DivExDate','DivPayDate','DivAmt','Open','High','Low','Last','OpenYld','HighYld','LowYld','ShortPrice','ShortVol','ShortTrdVol','ShortTurnnover','ShortWeighting','ShortLimit','AccVolume','Turnover','ImputedCls','ChangeType','OldValue','NewValue','Volatility','Strike','Premium','AucPrice','Auc Vol','MidPrice','FinEvalPrice','ProvEvalPrice','AdvancingIssues','DecliningIssues','UnchangedIssues','TotalIssues','AdvancingVolume','DecliningVolume','UnchangedVolume','TotalVolume','NewHighs','NewLows','TotalMoves','PercentageChange','AdvancingMoves','DecliningMoves','UnchangedMoves','StrongMarket','WeakMarket','ChangedMarket','MarketVolatility','OriginalDate','LoanAskVolume','LoanAskAmountTradingPrice','PercentageShortVolumeTradedVolume','PercentageShortPriceTradedPrice','ForecastNAV','PreviousDaysNAV','FinalNAV','30DayATMIVCall','60DayATMIVCall','90DayATMIVCall','30DayATMIVPut','60DayATMIVPut','90DayATMIVPut','BackgroundReference','DataSource','BidSpread','AskSpread','ContractPhysicalUnits','Miniumumquantity','NumberPhysicals','ClosingReferencePrice','ImbalanceQuantity','FarClearingPrice','NearClearingPrice','OptionAdjustedSpread','ZSpread','ConvexityPremium','ConvexityRatio','PercentageDailyReturn','InterpolatedCDSBasis','InterpolatedCDSSpread','ClosesttoMaturityCDSBasis','SettlementDate','EquityPrice','Parity','CreditSpread','Delta','InputVolatility','ImpliedVolatility','FairPrice','BondFloor','Edge','YTW','YTB','SimpleMargin','DiscountMargin','12MonthsEPS','UpperTradingLimit','LowerTradingLimit','AmountOutstanding','IssuePrice','GSpread','MiscValue','MiscValueDescription'], axis=1)
                # convert to datetime explicitly and add nanoseconds to same time stamps
                    chunk['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(chunk.datetime)
                #nanoseconds = df.groupby(['datetime']).cumcount()
                #df['datetime'] += np.array(nanoseconds, dtype='m8[ns]')  
                # drop empty prints and make sure all prices are valid
                    dfRic = chunk[(chunk["RIC"] == contract)]
                    if len(dfRic)>0:
                        print(dfRic)
                    if ~chunk.empty:
                        dft = dfRic[(dfRic["Type"] == "Trade")]
                        dft.dropna(subset = ["Volume"], inplace =True)
                        dft = dft.drop(["RIC","Type","BidPrice", "BidSize", "AskPrice", "AskSize"], axis=1)
                        dft = dft[(dft["Price"] > 0)]

                    # clean up bid and ask
                        dfq = dfRic[(dfRic["Type"] == "Quote")]
                        dfq.dropna(how = 'all', subset = ["BidSize","AskSize"], inplace =True)
                        dfq = dfq.drop(["RIC","Type","Price", "Volume"], axis=1)
                        dfq = dfq[(dfq["BidSize"] > 0) | (dfq["AskSize"] > 0)]
                        dfq = dfq.ffill()
                    else:
                        print("Empty")    
    #add to hdf and close if loop finished
                    hdf.append('trade', dft, format='table', data_columns=True)
                    hdf.append('quote', dfq, format='table', data_columns=True)
    hdf.close()
```

Comment: Can you explain what is slow and why exactly it is slow? Without more detail it is hard to guess what would help speed up the process.

Comment: You should try profiling and measuring the performance of your program to figure out which points are the slowest and whether memory or CPU power is the limiting factor. That will help you narrow down what particular changes could help you. Then you could also upload the slowest parts of your source code to a question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and ask for advice on improving its performance.

Comment: I would try to read gzipped CSV's in chunks, not unzipping them first - this way you should have much less IO (usually one of the slowest parts). Beside that having more RAM should allow you to have a bigger chunks or even to do it without chunking if your RAM will be approx. two times bigger compared to the resulting DF. Parallel processing on the same server/computer (if you mean DASK) can make everything much worse because of the overhead. If you need a real power look at the Apache PySpark SQL, but that would mean higher investments in to the Hadoop Cluster - just my 2 cents...

Comment: Hi, posted the code to give you a better idea. I am pretty sure it is the reading and chunking part which is time consuming.

Comment: I think using multiprocessing and specifying dtypes when creating dataframe will reduce the time.

Comment: i get dtypes but how do i usemultiprocessing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have quite a few things which can be optimized:

- first of all read only those columns that you really need instead of reading and then dropping them - use `usecols=list_of_needed_columns` parameter
- increase your chunksize - try it with different values - i would start with `10**5`
- don't use `chunk.apply(...)` for converting your datetimes - it's **very** slow - use pd.to_datetime(column, format='...') instead
- you can filter your data bit more efficiently when combining multiple conditions instead of doing it step-by-step:

Comment: thats great, will apply the changes- you are definitely right about the apply i forgot about that.